# New Canvas not visible unless I resise window

Tags: java, applet, paint, repaint, visible

Basically I am making a snake game and I want to swap between the Game Menu and the actual Snake Game at will so I have a variable `int visibleCanvas` and the switch bellow. So basically I set as false the main menu visibility and put the game as visible and focusable.

However the screen goes black and it wont draw the actual game untill I press the "full screen button" (windows) which then shows the game as I wanted it to.

Both menu and SnakeC and classes that extend Canvas.

```
switch (visibleCanvas) {
        case 0:
            menu.setBackground(Color.black);
            menu.setVisible(true);
            menu.setFocusable(true);
            menu.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(640, 480));
            break;

        case 1:
            menu.setVisible(false);
            snakeC.setBackground(Color.black);
            snakeC.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(640, 480));
            snakeC.setVisible(true);
            snakeC.setFocusable(true);
            snakeC.requestFocus();
            break;
}
```

Comment: The semantics of your code snippet makes me think you want to look into using a [`CardLayout`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not revalidating and repainting the Component hierarchy. If you don't do that, then your application window won't be redrawn directly, but only when required (such as after a resize).

By the way, if you're making a game, you may want to look into double buffering using BufferStrategy, as it may help to prevent flicker during animations, and allow you to repaint the Canvas periodically (ensuring a constant frame rate and, as such, smooth animations).

Otherwise, this piece of code demonstrates a working example that switches Canvas instances when the first is clicked (you can replace the MouseListener with whatever trigger you want yourself):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    final JFrame frame = new JFrame("Test");
    frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    final Canvas canvas1 = new Canvas();
    final Canvas canvas2 = new Canvas();
    canvas1.setBackground(Color.RED);
    canvas2.setBackground(Color.BLUE);
    canvas1.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
        @Override public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
            frame.remove(canvas1);
            frame.add(canvas2, BorderLayout.CENTER);
            System.out.println("Canvas switched to Canvas2");
            frame.revalidate();
        }
    });

    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        @Override public void run() {
            frame.add(canvas1);
            frame.setSize(640, 480);
            frame.setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: I actually am :/ And that's what is concerning me. I start a thread in the SnakeCanvas's run method where the first thing I do is repaint.

Comment: And you're sure the repaint() method is invoked _after_ the SnakeCanvas has been made visible?

Comment: yes. I start the thread and its the first thing in the run method:

public void run() {
 repaint();
 while(true) {
  if (!mainMenu) {
   if (this.direction != Direction.NO_DIRECTION) {
    move();
   }
  }
  repaint();


  try {
   Thread.currentThread();
   Thread.sleep(80);
  }
  catch (Exception e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
  }
 }
}

Comment: I have made a small, runnable example that correctly switches Canvas instances (altough in a slightly different way). I believe it does what you want to do. I'll add it to this answer.

Comment: I'll try and change mine based on yours but I am using an Applet and not a Frame. But maybe yours will help

Comment: Applets work in more or less the same way: you can still call add and remove on them, since they are Containers as well. So it shouldn't make much difference.

Comment: I think I have successfully solved the problem by simply revalidating the Canvas. Thank you so much @chronio